# Webstart trust self signing certificates

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, java-web-start, self-signed

i am developing a java application delivered with webstart to a specific number of machines runing windows xp-7 under my management. I want to self sign it but to get ride of the nasty security waning.

I sign my jar with:

```
jarsigner.exe -keypass <pass> -keystore keystore -storepass <pass> -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 -digestalg SHA-1 myapp.jar <alias>
```

I have tried 2 approaches, exporting it as PKCS12

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias <alias> -deststorepass <pass> -destkeypass <pass>
```

and as cert

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore keystore -alias <alias> -file myapp.cer
```

And loading those files in the security tab in the java control panel under the manage certificates option as secue site CA.

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: *"Webstart trust self signing certificates"*  *"How can i achieve this?"*  Do you have a time machine?

Comment: So... any tip on this?

Comment: *"So... any tip on this? "* 1) Invent a time machine. 2) Build it. 3) Visit the old world in which 'self signed' code was tolerated/allowed.

Comment: Several alternatives are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23529521/230513).